# How do I locate an .IPA file?

Tags: iphone, backup, whatsapp.app

The [instructions for a tool](https://github.com/residentsummer/watoi/) to move WhatsApp messages from Android to iOS say that I need to install:

```
* `Whatsapp.ipa` of the same version (google will help)
```

Whatsapp.ipa appears to be the app itself. How do I locate it? After backing up an iPhone using iTunes on a Mac, only the data seem to be in `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup` (with coded filenames). The apps do not seem to be there (as would be expected; that would be wasted storage).

A comment below [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29743193/704972) answer suggests that it's somewhere under `~/Library`, but

```
> find ~/Library/Group\ Containers -name "*what*" -print
```

yields nothing.

(I'm working my way through [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/310797/7985) problem.)

Comment: You can install the old but still available version of iTunes that supports apps here: https://support.apple.com/en_AU/downloads/itunes. All my apps are in /Users/[ME]/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications. However you should be able to install it the regular way (unless I am missing something in your question) the normal way, via the app store.